# showing a popup message after submitting a form in PHP

Tags: php

I tried many things in this forum but I can't get the redirect to work or anything for that matter. The way I wrote it, it displays a new page with a success message, but the user has to back up through the browser only to find themselves with all their info still displayed.

I need the boxes to clear out and display a success message pop up. How do I do this?

Thank you,

here is my php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "lotusms@outlook.com";
$email_subject = "Your email subject line";


function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back with the browser back button and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['phone']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['service']) ||
    !isset($_POST['bedrooms']) || 
    !isset($_POST['bathrooms'])){
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
}

$name = $_POST['name']; // required
$phone = $_POST['phone']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$service = $_POST['service']; // required
$bedrooms = $_POST['bedrooms']; // not required
$bathrooms = $_POST['bathrooms']; // not required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
   if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
     $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
     }
     $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
     if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
     $error_message .= 'The name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
     }

    $string_exp = "/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$phone)) {
     $error_message .= 'The number you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
      died($error_message);
     }
     $email_message = "The following quote has been requested. \n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Phone: ".clean_string($phone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Service: ".clean_string($service)."\n";
$email_message .= "Bedrooms: ".clean_string($bedrooms)."\n";
$email_message .= "Bathrooms: ".clean_string($bathrooms)."\n";


 // create email headers
  $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
  'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
 ?>

 <!-- include your own success html here -->

 <?php
  }
  ?>
```

and here is my form

```
<form action="bin/quote.php" method="post" id="search" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="alert('Thank you!')"; >
   <table summary="Search form" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5">                     
      <tr>
          <th style="color:#c1c2c3; font-weight:bold">REQUEST A QUOTE</th>
        </tr>                       
      <tr>
          <td colspan="5">Name: <input style="margin-left: 55px" type="text" class="text" name="name" /></td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
          <td colspan="10">Phone:<input style="margin-left: 55px" type="text" class="text" name="phone" placeholder="XXX-XXX-XXXX" /></td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
          <td colspan="5">Email:<input style="margin-left: 55px" type="text" class="text" name="email" /></td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
          <th>Service Required:</th>
        <td colspan="3">
           <select name="service">
              <option value="Residential Move">Residential Move*</option>
              <option value="Commercial Move">Commercial Move*</option>
              <option value="Storage Unit Loading">Storage Unit Loading</option>
              <option value="Storage Unit Unloading">Storage Unit Unloading</option>
              <option value="Furniture Consignment">Furniture Consignment</option>
              <option value="Assembly/Removal">Assembly/Removal</option>
              <option value="Landscaping">Landscaping</option>
              <option value="Cleanout">Cleanout</option>
              <option value="General Help">General Help</option>
           </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="color:#c1c2c3"><b>*If a move...</b></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Bedrooms:</th>
        <td>
           <select name="bedrooms">
               <option value="1">1</option>
               <option value="2">2</option>
               <option value="3">3</option>
               <option value="4">4</option>
               <option value="5">5+</option>
           </select>
        </td>                          
        <th>Bathrooms:</th>
        <td>
           <select name="bathrooms">
               <option value="1">1</option>
               <option value="2">2</option>
               <option value="3">3</option>
               <option value="4">4</option>
               <option value="5">5+</option>
           </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>                              
        <td><a onclick="document.getElementById('search').submit()"><button type="submit" value="SEND" class="more">Send</button></a></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</form>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a redirect:

```
...
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
header('location: success.php'); //send them wherever you want so they don't have to use back button
die();
```